# Drawing over a JPanel with the paint() method

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paint

I need to extend a `JPanel` so that upon a certain condition, it paints a semi-transparent overlay over the whole avaiable space.

From other answers I gathered that in this case, one should override `paint()` instead of `paintComponent(),` so that I can draw after the components have been painted, but I had no luck overriding either.

Overriding `paintComponent()` will draw behind the components on the `JPanel`.
Overriding paint() draws in front of them, but moving the mouse over the `JButtons` repaints them, and they come on top.

For example this will work, but the `JButtons` come on top if hovered:

```
@Override
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paint(g);  //also tried without this call
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
            g2d.setColor(BK_COLOR);
        g2d.fillRect(0,0,getWidth(), getHeight());      
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: *"From other answers I gathered that in this case, one should override paint() instead of paintComponent()"* - That's actually, not true, Swing components can be painted independently of their parent, meaning, your `paint` method may not be called when a child component repaints

Comment: I see. So how do I get around that? Because it seems like that's exactly the case. Surely I don't have to repaint it every time with a mouseListener on every JButton..?

Comment: Generally `JLayer`/`JXLayer` is a better solution, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29143251/how-to-make-a-blurry-jframe-jdialog-in-java-using-swing-and-jlayer/29143478#29143478), [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14286484/putting-marks-on-imageicon-in-jlabel/14287485#14287485) and [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12982863/secure-desktop-mode-effect-for-java-application/12983564#12983564)

Comment: Once upon a time, you would have had to resort to using the frame's `glassPane`, but now we `JLayer`, which is a kind of "glass pane for components", for my previous comment for some examples

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks it works just fine. Post this as an answer please, so I can select it and people can read, for generations to come !

Comment: [This one's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27516581/how-to-highlight-uniform-visually-select-draw-transparent-overlay-jpanel/27516784#27516784) probably closer to what your asking ;)